# How to press the back button using an intent in android?

Tags: android, back-button

I know to pass an intent to goto the home screen using this code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
```

But I want to press the back button using an intent in android.

Comment: Where is your code running (in an Application, a Service, ...?

Comment: My code is running in a service

Comment: You can't do this in a service, except if the device is rooted.

Comment: but we have the  assistant menu in samsung galaxy s4 which provides this function!

Comment: It is a violation of the design philosophy of Android to "take control" of the UI in a service.   Even if you can do it, you should not be doing it -- you will have very unhappy/annoyed users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override back pressed somewhere in your activity
`@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        //Do whatever custom stuff you wish here
        super.onBackPressed();
    }`

Then you may call backPressed in whatever way you may wish and wherever you may wish:

```
MyActivity.this.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: This does not work in a service and i want an intent to go back..PLEASE HELP ME